# Got any good stories of dangerous recording?

Tags: experiences, location-recording

I love living vicariously through other people experiences on this site.  So, I was wondering if anybody had any interesting stories of dangerous recording experiences.  Either harmful to yourself, your gear, or to anybody else.  Maybe you got a little to close to the explosion you were recording, or you were chased by a bear in full field recording gear. :)

Most of my recordings were done in the relative safety of the studio. Maybe some bumps and bruises, but not much more. That is why I ask if any of you had more risky experiences?

Who knows maybe we will learn a few things NOT to do while recording.

Answer (score 4):

The [implosion of Texas Stadium](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/483127-tx-stadium-implosion.html) was...interesting.

Comment: very nice!  there any way I could hear the non-mp3 version?

Comment: Sounds like some massive tribal drums or something on my laptop speakers. Very cool.

Answer (score 4):

For my student film I needed the sound of someone falling down a set of stairs in a house. I tried everything I could think of to recreate but nothing sounded any good. So I threw myself down and recorded that. Sounded great.

One needs to suffer for their art after all ;)

Comment: Haha, nice! LIkewise, i needed some body falls onto concrete once, back at school. It's funny how once you get into that foley/fx recording mindset, you don't stop until you get what you need.

Comment: So, are you saying if we ever need the sound of someone falling down the stairs we should just come to you?

Comment: I feel we've just created a niche here, stunt post production sound. For all your dangerous sound needs. No job too dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

A couple years back I was working on a movie in northern Minnesota about a grandfather teaching his grandson how to harvest wild rice.  We had a couple shots where the two guys delivered some dialogue while paddling their canoe through a rice paddy.  Originally the plan was to put the camera and audio folks on a pontoon boat and get close enough for the shot.  But, the lake water was a bit too choppy for a smooth video shot and we had some trouble with getting close enough for the shot due to the rice fields.  So, the DP/Camera op and myself put on waders, grabbed a couple 6 step ladders and trekked out about 300 feet into the lake.  Luckily nothing got dropped into the water and we got the shot with clean dialogue!

I have a photo of it on my website:  www.matthewfreed.com
Go to photos and it's the 5th one down.

This summer I'll be working on a movie that has both WWII and Iraq battle scenes with planes, tanks, armored personnel carriers, guns, and lots of explosions.  I hope I don't hurt myself or my gear!

Comment: Cool story and cool website.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find more stories on [this thread](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/408/sound-recording-disaster-stories), including my own of a lightning strike at 30ft. God was good to me that day.

Comment: How else would we know we're alive if we didn't have these incidents?

Comment: And here I thought I had searched all over for a similar question. Oh well...

Answer (score 3):

Back in my student days, we shot a short film on a prawn trawler. The people who ran the equipment store at uni would have flipped if they knew we were taking that gear out to sea. I remember lowering the 416 on a boom pole, at nearly full extension, to get close waves lapping. The whole time i was thinking "if a rogue wave comes, or if anything comes undone, i'm screwed". I kept recording though, i was on a mission!

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything scary enough to be worth posting from my own recording trips, but here's a link to a great article on recording "The Deadliest Catch."  It's on page 36.

http://www.coffeysound.com/media/CAF_-_Summer_2010.pdf

Answer (score 1):

filming russian firefighters who we're drunk & smoked cigarettes while flying way to old & heavy helicopters